# Is this jQuery like syntax valid in Java?

Tags: java

In c++, this chain-able syntax is invalid.

```
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    act.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
```

Comment: What makes you think that's invalid C++?

Comment: Yes, If you return an object, this chin-able code works. I was think this is a multiply method call just like the 'with' in VB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your methods return the same object, that will work fine.

It will work in C++ too, except for the anonymous inner classes. (which C++ doesn't support until C++0x)
However, in C++, it would be more performant to return pointers and use the `->` operator.

Comment: Yes, this depends entirely on the classes in question. It *could* be valid C++ or Java, and it could be invalid - it is not a language-dependent issue. If all of your builder methods have a signature like `public Builder setMessage(String)` and do `return this;` then this will have the intended effect.

Comment: @ZoFreX: That's why I said, _As long as your methods return the same object_.  He's asking about the syntax.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to clarify what he would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is question what your setters return. If they return `void` you can't obviously call anything on it again. If they return the changed object it will be valid.